# Facebook.api methods name docs

Tags: facebook, api, methods

Where can i get the Facebook.api methods name such as to get logged in user friends then we call following method

Facebook.api('/me/friends')

I want to know where is the documentation about request methods string like '/me/friends' , '/me/albums' etc.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such "documentation" for the ALL the request methods.

But you can take a look at : [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me)

[image: sd]

Answer (score 0):

A lot of info can be found on the following links:

[Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

[Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/)